# PHP MySql - Check if value exists

Tags: php, mysql

Need to check if both the `EMAIL_ADDRESS` and `ACTIVATION_CODE` exist within a MySql Table, if so return `"Code is valid"`,else `"Code is NOT valid"`.

At present it's always returning code not valid, however I've checked the record in the table and the queried code does exist.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$acticode = $_POST['code'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xActivate WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS='$email' AND ACTIVATION_CODE='$acticode' LIMIT 1");

 if (mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo 'Code is valid';
} else {
    echo 'Code is NOT valid';
}
```

Comment: Try with the email address `' OR 1=1 --`. Then it'll work. Else try to ask mysql_error() and read up on escaping, or parameterized queries.

Comment: Can you echo out the query and run it manually to verify everything is correct? Maybe the column names should be lower case?

Comment: @mario Should there not be a `DROP ALL TABLES` thrown in for good measure?

Comment: @mario where should I insert these?
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xActivate WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS='$email' AND ACTIVATION_CODE='$acticode' LIMIT 1");

Answer (score 3):

But this code is not secure:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$acticode = $_POST['code'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xActivate WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS='$email' AND ACTIVATION_CODE='$acticode' LIMIT 1");
$data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
 if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo 'Code is valid';
} else {
    echo 'Code is NOT valid';
}
```

To secure and prevent SQL Injection:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$acticode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code']);
```

Please note:

https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

> Warning
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
> used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
> information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> ```
>     mysqli_real_escape_string()
>     PDO::quote()
> ```

Comment: mysql is deprecated, use mysqli. Also, use bindParam() for the $email and $acticode parameters.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this warning, I will leave a Note in my answer. Thank you