# PHP MySql - Confirm row value exists

Tags: php, mysql

Creating a script that generates a random code when user sign's up and places it in a two column MySql table. Column Names are `"EMAIL_ADDRESS"` and `"ACTIVATION_CODE"`.   User then get's an email with a link to `activate.php?code=CODE1234&email=email@email.com`, which contains:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$acticode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xActivate WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS='$email' AND ACTIVATION_CODE='$acticode' LIMIT 1");

if (!mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
   echo 'Code is valid';
} else {
   echo 'Code is NOT valid';
}
```

Problem is the code is always returning Not Valid. I need the script to check that both the email and code match up. If not return `"Not Valid"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [23038631](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038631/php-mysql-check-if-value-exists).

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli` functions with `mysql_*` library, what you want is `mysql_num_rows($result)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this code:

- You should use `$_GET` and not `$_POST`
- You are combining `mysql` and `mysqli` functions, you need to pick one of them.
- I would recommend using `mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0` instead of `!mysql_num_rows($result)`.
- Although you escape the characters, there are safer ways to do this. For instance if later another form of SQL injection is found (although this is very unlikely), MySql library is simply modified and will protect all previously defined queries.