# PHP MySql - Check if column B matches GET input

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database table with two columns:
**EMAIL_ADDRESS** and **ACTIVATION_CODE**

I need to make the script check if the Activation Code the user has submitted in the URL, matches the Email Address in the table. So far this isn't working.

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$acticode = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['code']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xActivate WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS='$email',1");

if ($result = '$acticode') {
   echo 'Code is valid';
} else {
   echo 'Code is NOT valid';
}
```

Comment: This is 3rd consecutive same question you are posting.

Comment: And you already have a [*correct answer here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23038669/767881), but you didn't accept it yet.

Comment: This is getting worse. Please stop reposting your own questions.

Comment: @ScottMcGready The question's are different but related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the column in the database where the code is stored, also, you need to actually get the data

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$acticode = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['code']);

$code_found = false;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM xActivate WHERE EMAIL_ADDRESS='$email',1");
if($result) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  if($row) {
    if ($row['codefield'] == $acticode) {
        $code_found = true;       
    }

  }
}

if($code_found) {
   echo 'Code is valid';
} else {
   echo 'Code is NOT valid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check row with `mysql_num_row`

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){...}
```

and check valid code with

```
if(mysql_error())
```